# Email delivery logs for members of Group

Tags: google-workspace

I currently do not have admin access to G Suite, but I am interested in knowing whether Email Log Search would allow me to track email delivery for an email sent to a Groups address. The email was forwarded to a set of recipients, but one is claiming not to be receiving it.

All references I've found state that you should put the Groups address in the TO field, but would that return information about delivery status to individual recipients in the group? If the Groups address were to be set as the FROM, would I be able to track delivery to group members?

I have also seen that there's a status check for group members in the group itself, but that seems to be a general tag and cannot be narrowed down to a specific email.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When an email is sent to a group email address, the email will be forwarded to all the individual emails that are members of that group. So if you set the groups email on the TO field it will not return the delivery status to the individual recipients.

> Note that if you are the domain primary admin it is also possible to see the individual addresses by clicking the `Expand Results to All Recipients` button.

But if you set the group email as the FROM, it will show the forwarded emails to the individual member emails.

For more information on Email Log Search, please refer to https://support.google.com/a/answer/2618874